# Surface extraction a fluid .

Tags: algorithm

At a given time-step I have a sampled a lot points from a  fluid , and I want to extract the
points which lie at the surface of the fluid. Does any one know a good algorithm 
and any available codes to do this?

I am aware of surface reconstruction, but the assumption there is that the sampled points
are on/near the surface. So I guess that would not be too useful here.

Comment: Look up "Voroni tesselation".

Comment: What format is your data?  I mean, if its done by depth it would be pretty easy, no?  I don't understand exactly what the problem is?

Comment: No I don't have data by depth. I just have an unorganized collection of (x,y,z) coordinates and I wish to extract the surface points.

Comment: I think we need more information. You have a collection of (x,y,z) points that exist within the fluid, right? And you're trying to find the plane that bounds these points? Is the surface necessarily parallel to the x-y plane or no?

Comment: The fluid is not static, the fluid is sloshing about. For a given time-step I wanted to extract the free-surface. So the problem is coordinate system independent.

Answer (score 1):

Is finding the convex hull of the points adequate? How many points do you have?

Maybe start with a convex hull and then modify it to allow a certian amount of concavity where there are large parts of the surface without any points nearby.

Otherwise try fitting a spline or similar polynomial function to the points. You need some sort of cost metric to measure how good your fit is so that you don't bend your surface too much to reach the inner points. (Unless sharp high curvature sections are allowed for breaking waves etc?)

Is this a tank that get's moved about causing sloshing or something similar - if so there may be some physics model you can used to suggest the shape of surfaces likely to be found. The pattern of motion and speed of waves in the fluid may tell you how many waves etc you'd see.